# Regexp in R: catch LaTeX references such as \autocite{author1}{author2} with any number of authors.

Tags: regex, r

Having spent two days on experimenting, reading regexp help and R FAQ, I must resign and ask for mercy here.

#### My task

I have a text file, containing LaTeX code, a scientific article. The text features multiple citations in biblatex format, for example `\autocite{author1}{author2}`, where the number of author-brackets can range from 1 to, let's say, 20 for practical purposes. Due to the requirements of a journal I have to replace these citations with the ones in another format: `\cite{author1,author2}`, where the number of authors, obviously, corresponds to the original number.

#### My tentative solution

Ok, I thought, let's write a parser in R and be done with that. I just need a function to do the replacement as described above, and a regular expression to be used in a function `gsubfn()`, which is a version of `gsub()` that can take a function for its `replacement=` argument. Here is that function:

```
parsecite <- function(x) {
library(stringr)

### extracts all references (without square brackets)
refs <- str_match_all(x,'\\{(.*?)\\}')[[1]][,2] 

### constructs the \cite format
out <- paste0('\\cite{',str_c(refs,collapse=','),'}') 
return(out)
}
```

To give an example of how it works:

```
testref <- '\autocites{author1}{author2}'
parsecite(testref)
# [1] "\\cite{author1,author2}"

cat(parsecite(testref))
# \cite{author1,author2}
```

Works like it should I believe. So, my last step would be using the function:

```
gsubfn(SOME.REGEX,parsecite,MYINPUT)
```

where MYINPUT would be the result of `readLines()` from the original textfile.

#### My question

How could I construct the regular expression SOME.REGEX so that it would capture citations with any number of authors? That is, both `\autocite{author1}` as well as `\autocite{author1}{author2}{author3}`? Keep in mind that there may be multiple citations in the text (possibly on the same line). If the closing curly bracket is not followed by an opening curly bracket, this means the end of a citation. A citation always starts with the backslash.

Is it possible to do this with R (not Perl) regular expressions? If not, Perl regex are also fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Can the citation be spread over multiple lines?

Comment: I'm sure this won't solve the problem, but should `\autocites` in `testref` be `\\autocite`?

Comment: @James An excellent question. I must say I am not sure, probably not. The .tex file is actually an export of an antecedent Markdown file, converted through pandoc. As far as I can see, pandoc treats each reference as a single word, and will try to put it on the same line. I'll have to try to create a very long reference to be sure, and I'll come back with that. But for all practical purposes let's say that citations are not spread over multiple lines.

Comment: @JamesTrimble Both are possible (along with `\textcite{}`), the solution will be similar, of course. As far as I can see, \autocite is used with a single author, and \autocites with multiple authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below. The regular expression searches for `\autocite`, followed by any number of `{...}` groups (which can each contain any characters except `}`). I also added `backref=0` to the call to `gsubfn()`.

```
library(gsubfn)
MYINPUT <- paste("TEST \\autocite{author1}{author2}",
                 "TEST \\autocite{author3}",
                 "TEST \\somethingelse{author4} TEST")

autocite_regex <- "\\\\autocite(\\{[^\\}]*?\\})*"
gsubfn(autocite_regex, parsecite, MYINPUT,backref=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, James, that works. After a few minutes I even figured out what the [^\\}]*? part does. Cheers!